All gridlines with some tick labels
For my thesis I have to plot graphs for pretty big value range (from 10^-6 to 10^14). I want to have all the gridlines but only some tick labels.
all the gridlines
but only some tick labels
Example I've made to make testing easier:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

start=1e-6
stop= 1e14
I_out_tab = []
x=np.power(np.divide(stop, start), np.divide(1, 1000))
for i in range(0,1000):
    I_out_tab.append(start * np.power(x,i))

y=[]
for i in I_out_tab:
    y.append( 2 * i**3)




plt.loglog(I_out_tab, y)
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10, subs='all', numticks=100))
plt.show()


Any ideas?

Setting the minor locator without tick labels: ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10, subs='all', numticks=100))and ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.NullFormatter()). The major locator can keep its default.
